# Parsing portions of string into dictionary?

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, text-parsing, string-parsing

I am not familiar with string parsing libraries; and would like to go from:

```
'foo=5 z v xz er bar=" hel o" c z a == "hi" b = "who"'
```

To this parsed dictionary:

```
{'foo':5, 'bar': ' hel o', 'a': 'hi', b: 'who'}
```

But I am not sure where to begin. Could you please give me some advice for handling this conversion?

Comment: So the `v`, `xz`, `er`, etc things that don't have an equals sign are just dropped on the floor?  Also, the place to begin in Python is probably [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html).

Comment: Everything without an `=` or `==` should not be present in the dictionary. (I'm dealing with them in a separate phase)

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions. See [python's documentation on regex](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) or [tutorial's point tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

Something like this can work:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(\w+ ?=+ ?\d+|\w+ ?=+ ?\"(?: *\w*)*\")")

#your example string:
s = 'foo=5 z v xz er bar=" hel o" c z a == "hi" b = "who"'

matches = regex.findall(s)

dict1 = {}
for m in matches:
    elems = m.split("=")
    #elems[0] = key
    #elems[len(elems)-1] = value, to account for the case of multiple ='s

    try:
        #see if the element is a number
        dict1[str(elems[0])] = int(elems[len(elems) - 1]) 

    except:
        #if type casting didn't work, just store it as a string
        dict1[str(elems[0])] = elems[len(elems) - 1]
```

Here's the regular expression broken down:

```
(\w+ ?=+ ?\d+|\w+ ?=+ ?\"(?: *\w*)*\")
```

`\w+` means one or more alphanumeric characters.

`\d+` means one or more digits.

`(?:regex)*` means match 0 or more copies of the regex without assigning it a group #.

`(regex1|regex2)` means find a string that matches with regex1 or matches with regex2.

`\"` is the escape sequence for quotation mark.

`=+` means match one or more "=" signs

`_?` means match 0 or 1 spaces (pretend the "_" is a space)

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing is a parsing library that lets you build up your matching expression a bit at a time.

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphanums, nums, oneOf, quotedString, removeQuotes

identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums)
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
value = integer | quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)

# equals could be '==' or '='
# (suppress it so it does not get included in the resulting tokens)
EQ = oneOf("= ==").suppress()

# define the expression for an assignment
assign = identifier + EQ + value
```

Here is the code to apply this parser

```
# search sample string for matching assignments
s = 'foo=5 z v xz er bar=" hel o" c z a == "hi" b = "who"'
assignments = assign.searchString(s)
dd = {}
for k,v in assignments:
    dd[k] = v

# or more simply
#dd = dict(assignments.asList())

print dd
```

Gives:

```
{'a': 'hi', 'b': 'who', 'foo': 5, 'bar': ' hel o'}
```